# Execute remote command through Fabric in Python

Tags: python, ssh, root, fabric

I want to log on a remote ubuntu machine with 'host' ip and run commands as root. This is what I have:

```
from fabric import Connection


class RemoteShell:

def __init__(self, host):
    self.host = host
    self.user = 'root'
    self.password = 'pkey'
    self.key_file = get_key_file_path()

def execute(self, command):
    with Connection(
            self.host,
            user=self.user,
            connect_kwargs={"pkey": self.password, "key_filename": self.key_file}
    ) as c:
        message = c.run(command)
        return message
```

In another file, I go

```
client = RemoteShell(target_ip)
result = client.execute('iwconfig')
```

When running execute I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no fingerprint. I also note when I see the properties of 'c' in my IDE the is_connected attribute is False, although I'm reading the correct pkey and filepath. I have no problem to connect through ssh manually as well

Comment: I believe the pkey argument is intended to be a paramiko PKey object, not a string. https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect Why are you passing both a password and a private key? Is one not sufficient?

Comment: This is the password I need when I manually run ssh-add key-file on my system. The term might be passphrase instead?